# How do I refer to two different classes by one name in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have two classes to handle database operations, one for MySQL (DBMySQL), and another for SQLite (DBSQLite). The user chooses which database system to use.

The functions within the classes have the same names, but are obviously slightly different to handle the variations in databases.

I would like to refer to the chosen class by one name throughout the application. I have set a global variable DB.

In a procedure I can: Dim DB as New DBMySQL (or DBSQLite). This works within the procedure, but not globally, but I can see all the functions when coding.

If I instead use: DB = New DBMySQL, this works globally, but no class functions are displayed when coding.

Any alternatives?

Comment: Are you looking for `Abstract Factory Pattern`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the concept of [inheritance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973803.aspx), and create a [MustInherit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aee8f02w.aspx) class with [MustOverride](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyb29zk8.aspx) methods and/or properties.

```
Public MustInherit Class AbstractDB

    Public MustOverride Function MyQuery(input As Object) As Object

    Public MustOverride Sub MyUpdateMethod(input As Object)

End Class

Public Class DBMySQL
    Inherits AbstractDB

    Public Overrides Function MyQuery(input As Object) As Object

    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub MyUpdateMethod(input As Object)

    End Sub
End Class

Public Class DBSQLite
    Inherits AbstractDB

    Public Overrides Function MyQuery(input As Object) As Object

    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub MyUpdateMethod(input As Object)

    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, when you want to use your classes, make your DB global variable of type AbstractDB.  You could then create either DBMySql or DBSQLite and assign it to your DB variable.  The method names will all be the same, because they all inherit the same base class.  But each derived class must fill out the content of those methods on its own.

```
    Dim DB as AbstractDB = New DBMySQL
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, that works! I did have to initially declare:
Public DB as AbstractDB = New DBMySQL
in order to see functions when coding, then when I knew which class to use, i assigned:
DB = New DBSQLite.
Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use an interface.

```
Public Interface IRepository
  ' common functions of MySQL and SQLLiteclasses
End Interface

Public Class MySQLRepository
    Implements IRepository
End Class

Public Class SQLLiteRepository
    Implements IRepository
End Class

Public Function GetDB(userChoice As String) As IRepository
 If userChoice = "MySQL" Then
   Return New MySQLRepository()
 Else
   Return New SQLLiteRepository
 End if
End Function

Dim DB As IRepository = GetDB(userChoice)
```

This is a basic implementation of the [Repository](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/) pattern.  The example in the link is in C#, but, as you're probably aware, it's not easy finding examples in VB. Fortunately, there are lots of C# to VB converters.

The abstract example Sean Skelly gave should also work.  You may want to research the difference between abstract classes and interfaces.

Comment: Yes, inheritance and interfaces are two different approaches, each with pluses and minuses.  For me, it comes down to whether or not your classes will do anything else beyond a narrow scope.  If so, you can implement multiple interfaces, but can only inherit one type.